# i get this error TRG_Codeupdate: System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001 how to control this?

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class CLS_CodetabelleChange {
    
    public void splitupdate(List<Account> AccountListe){
          List<Account>updateListe=new List<Account>();
          List<Account>restListe=new List<Account>();
          if (!AccountListe.isEmpty()){
          for (Integer i = 0; i < AccountListe.size(); i++) {
                if (i < 49999) {
                    updateListe.add(AccountListe.get(i));
                }else{
                    restListe.add(AccountListe.get(i));
                }
              }
              update updateListe;
              splitupdate(restListe);
          }
    }

    public void splitupdate(List<Buchungskreis__c> BuchungskreisListe){
      List<Buchungskreis__c>updateListe=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
      List<Buchungskreis__c>restListe=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
      if (!BuchungskreisListe.isEmpty()){
      for (Integer i = 0; i < BuchungskreisListe.size(); i++) {
            if (i < 49999) {
                updateListe.add(BuchungskreisListe.get(i));
            }else{
                restListe.add(BuchungskreisListe.get(i));
            }
          }
          update updateListe;
          splitupdate(restListe);
      }
}

public void updatecode1(List<Codetabelle__c> newcode, List<Codetabelle__c> oldcode){
    List<Account>A1=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A2=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A3=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A4=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A5=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A6=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A7=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A8=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A9=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A10=new List<Account>();
    List<Buchungskreis__c>B1=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
    List<Buchungskreis__c>B2=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
    
    for (Codetabelle__c c1: newcode){
        for (Codetabelle__c c2: oldcode){
            if (c1.id==c2.id){
                if(c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c!=c2.BuchungskreisFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BuKr__c from Account where BuKr__c =:c2.BuchungskreisFormel__c]))
                {Account A11=new Account(id=acc1.id,BuKr__c =c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c);                     
                 A1.add(A11);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.KontengruppenFormel__c!=c2.KontengruppenFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kontengr__c from Account where Kontengr__c =:c2.KontengruppenFormel__c]))
                {Account A21=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kontengr__c =c1.KontengruppenFormel__c);                     
                 A2.add(A21);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.KundengruppenFormel__c!=c2.KundengruppenFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundengrp__c from Account where Kundengrp__c =:c2.KundengruppenFormel__c]))
                {Account A31=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundengrp__c =c1.KundengruppenFormel__c);                     
                 A3.add(A31);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c!=c2.KundenbezirkeFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundenbezirk__c from Account where Kundenbezirk__c =:c2.KundenbezirkeFormel__c]))
                {Account A41=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundenbezirk__c =c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c);                     
                 A4.add(A41);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c!=c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_uferg__c from Account where Verk_uferg__c =:c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c]))
                {Account A51=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_uferg__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
                 A5.add(A51);}
                 
                 for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verk_ufergruppe__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verk_ufergruppe__c =:c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c]))
                {Buchungskreis__c B11=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verk_ufergruppe__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
                 B1.add(B11);}
                
                }
                else 
                    if(c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c!=c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_Buero__c from Account where Verk_Buero__c =:c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c]))
                {Account A61=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_Buero__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
                 A6.add(A61);}
                 
                for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verkaufsb_ro__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verkaufsb_ro__c =:c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c]))
                {Buchungskreis__c B21=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verkaufsb_ro__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
                 B2.add(B21);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.Laender__c!=c2.Laender__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BillingCountry from Account where BillingCountry =:c2.Laender__c]))
                {Account A71=new Account(id=acc1.id,BillingCountry =c1.Laender__c);                     
                 A7.add(A71);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c!=c2.BranchenschluesselFormel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Branche_SAP__c from Account where Branche_SAP__c =:c2.BranchenschluesselFormel__c]))
                {Account A81=new Account(id=acc1.id,Branche_SAP__c =c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c);                     
                 A8.add(A81);}}
                else 
                    if(c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c!=c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verkaeufergruppe1__c, Verkaeufergruppe2__c, LZLD_Gebiet__c,LZLD_Region__c, Regional_Leiter__c, LFB__c from Account where Verkaeufergruppe1__c =:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or Verkaeufergruppe2__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LZLD_Gebiet__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LZLD_Region__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or Regional_Leiter__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LFB__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c]))
                {Account A91=new Account(id=acc1.id);
                 if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Verkaeufergruppe1__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Verkaeufergruppe2__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 if(acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LZLD_Gebiet__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 if(acc1.LZLD_Region__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LZLD_Region__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 if(acc1.Regional_Leiter__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Regional_Leiter__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 if(acc1.LFB__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LFB__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                 A9.add(A91);}}
                else
                    if(c1.Status_Profitcenter__c!=c2.Status_Profitcenter__c)
                {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Status_Profitcenter__c from Account where Status_Profitcenter__c =:c2.Status_Profitcenter__c]))
                {Account A111=new Account(id=acc1.id,Status_Profitcenter__c =c1.Status_Profitcenter__c);                     
                 A10.add(A111);}}
                
            }
        }
    }
    splitupdate(A1);
    splitupdate(A2);
    splitupdate(A3);
    splitupdate(A4);
    splitupdate(A5);
    splitupdate(A6);
    splitupdate(A7);
    splitupdate(A8);
    splitupdate(A9);
    splitupdate(A10);
    splitupdate(B1);
    splitupdate(B2);
    
}

public void insertcode1(List<Codetabelle__c> newcode){
    List<Account>A1=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A2=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A3=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A4=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A5=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A6=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A7=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A8=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A9=new List<Account>();
    List<Account>A10=new List<Account>();
    List<Buchungskreis__c>B1=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
    List<Buchungskreis__c>B2=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
    
    for (Codetabelle__c c1: newcode){
        if(c1.BuchungskreisID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BuKr__c from Account where BuKr__c =:c1.BuchungskreisID__c]))
        {Account A11=new Account(id=acc1.id,BuKr__c =c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c);                     
         A1.add(A11);}}
        else 
            if(c1.KontengruppenID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kontengr__c from Account where Kontengr__c =:c1.KontengruppenID__c]))
        {Account A21=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kontengr__c =c1.KontengruppenFormel__c);                     
         A2.add(A21);}}
        else 
            if(c1.KundengruppenID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundengrp__c from Account where Kundengrp__c =:c1.KundengruppenID__c]))
        {Account A31=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundengrp__c =c1.KundengruppenFormel__c);                     
         A3.add(A31);}}
        else 
            if(c1.KundenbezirkeID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundenbezirk__c from Account where Kundenbezirk__c =:c1.KundenbezirkeID__c]))
        {Account A41=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundenbezirk__c =c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c);                     
         A4.add(A41);}}
        else 
            if(c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_uferg__c from Account where Verk_uferg__c =:c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c]))
        {Account A51=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_uferg__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
         A5.add(A51);}
         
        for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verk_ufergruppe__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verk_ufergruppe__c =:c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c]))
        {Buchungskreis__c B11=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verk_ufergruppe__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
         B1.add(B11);}}
        else 
            if(c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_Buero__c from Account where Verk_Buero__c =:c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c]))
        {Account A61=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_Buero__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
         A6.add(A61);}
        
        for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verkaufsb_ro__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verkaufsb_ro__c =:c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c]))
        {Buchungskreis__c B21=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verkaufsb_ro__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
         B2.add(B21);}}
        else 
            if(c1.Laendercode__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BillingCountry from Account where BillingCountry =:c1.Laendercode__c]))
        {Account A71=new Account(id=acc1.id,BillingCountry =c1.Laender__c);                     
         A7.add(A71);}}
        else 
            if(c1.BranchenschluesselID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Branche_SAP__c from Account where Branche_SAP__c =:c1.BranchenschluesselID__c]))
        {Account A81=new Account(id=acc1.id,Branche_SAP__c =c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c);                     
         A8.add(A81);}}
        else 
            if(c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verkaeufergruppe1__c, Verkaeufergruppe2__c, LZLD_Gebiet__c,LZLD_Region__c, Regional_Leiter__c, LFB__c from Account where Verkaeufergruppe1__c =:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or Verkaeufergruppe2__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LZLD_Gebiet__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LZLD_Region__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or Regional_Leiter__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LFB__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c]))
        {Account A91=new Account(id=acc1.id);
         if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         if(acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         if(acc1.LZLD_Region__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LZLD_Region__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         if(acc1.Regional_Leiter__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Regional_Leiter__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         if(acc1.LFB__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LFB__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
         A9.add(A91);}}
        else
            if(c1.Status_Profitcenter_ID__c!=null)
        {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Status_Profitcenter__c from Account where Status_Profitcenter__c =:c1.Status_Profitcenter_ID__c]))
        {Account A111=new Account(id=acc1.id,Status_Profitcenter__c =c1.Status_Profitcenter__c);                     
         A10.add(A111);}}      
    }
    
    splitupdate(A1);
    splitupdate(A2);
    splitupdate(A3);
    splitupdate(A4);
    splitupdate(A5);
    splitupdate(A6);
    splitupdate(A7);
    splitupdate(A8);
    splitupdate(A9);
    splitupdate(A10);
    splitupdate(B1);
    splitupdate(B2);
    
}
```

}

Trigger:

```
trigger TRG_Codeupdate on Codetabelle__c (after insert, after update) {
    CLS_CodetabelleChange C1 =new CLS_CodetabelleChange();
    if(trigger.isinsert){
        c1.insertcode1(trigger.new);
    }
    else if(trigger.isupdate){
        c1.updatecode1(trigger.new, trigger.old);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001` error is thrown if you are trying to perform a DML operation on more than 10,000 records at a time.

Looking at your code, even without the stack trace, it seems mostly related to the `update` statement, as you are inserting up to 50,000 records to be updated. You can include some debug statements before the `update updateListe` so that you can see the size of the list you're trying to perform the DML operation on.